# dynamically insert css within php file

Tags: php, css

In a WordPress site I have style.php and in style.php echo CSS value which control from admin panel such as color skins, font styles. This working great, but I want to control options from frontend such as href attribute e.g `<code><pre><a href="http://example.com?color-red">Red Skin</a></pre></code>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the value in the address bar like

```
http://example.com/?skin=red-skin
```

This can be done by selecting the css via a switch or if statement. Now the tricky part comes for each sub page. Now you can create a session variable

```
 $_SESSION['skin'] = 'red-skin';
```

Each page then would look for the session value or use the default using a switch/if statement.

### SAMPLE SWITCH STATEMENT

```
 if(isset($_GET['skin'])) {
   $skin=$_GET['skin'];
   $_SESSION['skin']=$skin;
 } else {
   $skin=$_SESSION['skin']
 }
 switch(true){
    case($skin = 'red-skin'):
       echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/style_red.php" />';
       break;
    default:
       echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/style.php" />';
       break;
 }
```

Only downside of a SESSION variable is it is only good for the time the person is on the site or for 15-20 min of idle time on site. Depending on how the server is set up. If you have people that can change how it looks for them being logged in. You are better off creating a table and storing the user and skin choice and selecting/updating when required.

### EDIT

When calling the css/php file:

```
 <?
 if(isset($_GET['skin'])) {
   $skin=$_GET['skin'];
   $_SESSION['skin']=$skin;
 } else {
   $skin=$_SESSION['skin']
 }
 ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/templates/css/style.php?color=<? echo $skin; ?>" />
```

in CSS put the switch/if statement to breakdown the css

Comment: i want to use this for my wordpress theme,s demo preview site my all css styles are in 1 php file called style.php divide into sections control via options panel such as <?php $skin = get_option('skins'); if ($skin == 'blue') { echo some css } ?>

Comment: do you have a sample of your one of your css classes

Comment: You could have it so it piggy backs a color scheme. EX: if ($skin == 'blue') { $skin="blue" } <p class="title <? echo $skin ?>"> This would cause it to call two classes: 1) title 2) blue

Comment: <code><?php require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '../../../../../wp-config.php');
header("Content-type: text/css");

$skin = get_option('cap_skin');
if ($skin == 'Sky Blue') { // Sky Blue Skin
echo "
/* ----------- featured Panel -------------- */

.featured-wrap {background:url('../images/sky_blue/featured_bg.png') repeat-x;}
.featured-top {background:url('../images/sky_blue/featured_top_bg.png') center top no-repeat;}
.featured-bot {background:url('../images/sky_blue/featured_bot_bg.png') center bottom no-repeat;}";
}
?></code>

Comment: the edited code will work in most pages and carry over to the pages

Comment: call it as a normal stylesheet and add the ending. As a php file, the server will remove what is not required. I have my stylesheets as php so i can include compression.

Answer (score 0):

```
p { color: <?php echo (isset($_GET['color-red'])) ? "#FF0000" : "#000000" ?> }
```

You could do this as well..

```
switch($_GET['color']) {
case "red":
$color = "#FF0000";
break;

// etc..

default:
$color = "#000000";
break;
}

...
```

```
p { color: <?php echo $color ?> }
```

Then use..

http://example.com?color=red